# Test address is aligned at n byte just checks the lower 8-bit not the whole bits

Tags: assembly, alignment

i have a question about testing address whether is aligned at N-BYTE boundary ....

**consider that we are in 64-BIT mode ....**

in C language, we do something like this :

```
if(((unsigned long) str & 15) == 0) {}
```

here we check the whole 64-BIT address **(test str & 15)**

but i saw the generated assembly code and the generated code is:

```
test dil, 15
```

in fact, it's going to test just the lower 8-bit !!! so why it's just test the lower 8-bit and it's not something like this

```
test rdi, 15
```

or even this

```
test edi, 15
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found my answer .... when we want to check an address is aligned at 16-byte boundary or not, it's just important to check the first 4-bit of address whether is zero or not ... so it's ok to check just the lower 8-bit of the address ...

Comment: ... and there is no `test r32, imm8` encoding, so `test edi, imm32` would take more space for the zeros in the immediate.  The way `test` works (bitwise and), ignoring high bytes is always the same as masking them to zero with a wide mask of high zeros.